# Most efficient way to switch order in which data is read in assembly

Tags: microcontroller, assembly, code

I have an assembly assignment that requires me to be able to store a number and via a lookup table output the number on a 7 seg display in both forward and reverse order depending on the state of an input switch.
While it's not a requirement, I'd like to use the least number of cycles and code that I can and still follow good coding practices.

My current thinking is to store the number twice( once in either direction) and choose the starting memory address depending on the switch state. This way I only need one lookup routine that essentially reads either number in a fwd direction.

An alternative I have considered is to have two lookup routines. One that inc Z and one that decrements it. This has the obvious advantage of only requiring one stored number at the expense of additional lines of code.

Are either of these approaches acceptable or are there other methods I've not considered?

I tend to think the former is more effective but less flexible than the latter.

Comment: Can you clarify what you're trying to do?  Maybe give one or two examples of how you want this to work? How many entries are there in the lookup table?

Comment: @Doov Yes. The fwd or rev order is controlled by the pin state. The stored number is fixed and 6 digits. With the LUT containing 0 through to 9.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

strongly recommend you do not try to "*use the least number of cycles and code that I can*".

This will make it pointlessly hard to succeed.

I strongly recommend you get the program working first, using the technical approach you feel most comfortable with.

Then if you have any remaining time, polish the code in any way you like.

Experienced professional developers call efforts like "*use the least number of cycles and code that I can*" **premature optimisation**.

It is one of the major causes of failure to deliver adequate software on time.

Personally, I find getting working solutions first, aiming to have it mostly working in about 40% of the time, usually gives me insight into better strategies for solving the problem.

A good understanding of the problem, and a working 'test bed' which solves the problem, which I can manipulate, and run test against, will usually beat small-scale tactics like focusing on minimal instructions or fewest cycles every time.

If you want to build a program which is in some way optimal, build a simple program which you understand first.

Making a program that works, work better is almost always easier than trying to make a constrained (smallest, fastest, ...) program work at all.

I am very familiar with C, and pretty good with AVR. So I would probably write it in C first, as simply as I could, then read the assembler output from the compiler. It won't write code like a human learning to code. It'll likely be much better. However it'll give most of the instructions needed, and a target to beat.

I think having the number stored once, and using the switch to decide two things:

1. which end to start, and
2. what to add to the address of the start position (-1)

might be pretty straightforward. The display routine will take those two values in as parameters (-1 in  register and the start address in another pair)

Edit:
AFAIK, the AVR processor was deliberately designed to be a target for C compilers (which makes your assignment seem a little bit odd, but it is likely effective at helping understand what is going on 'under the covers'). So you may be able to do better, but gcc should be reasonably good, and a relatively easy match to the C.

It might do a few weird tricks, because, AFAIK, it has been polished for more than 15 years, so it may have sneaky tricks to shave a cycle or an instruction here and there

Comment: Very good points. I am just in the pseudo code stage at the minute so not invested either way yet. You gauged my efforts correctly though I should be focusing on getting anything working first! I do have a tendency to chase metaphorical rabbits :)

Comment: Have you used the Arduino IDE, and can you already write C? If you can, you can probably write a solution pretty quick (no more than a day), and you wont get too invested because you can't hand it in, but you might have a fall-back.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Thats a good strategy to see how gcc handles it!

Answer (score 1):

Not all assembly language is created equal - I'm going to use ARM assembly, supported by GCC 4.8, for this answer.

If I was asked to do this in C, I would almost certainly just start at the top of an array, and then decrement through it. This selection could be made by some type of if statement - whatever is desirable in your code.

Something like this:

`int sumListBackward(int *numPtr, int listLen)
{
  int acc = 0;
  int i;
  for(i = (listLen - 1); i >= 0; i--)
  {
    acc += *(numPtr+i);
  }
  return acc;
}`

Produces an assembly output of something like this (again, ARM gcc 4.8.2)

```
sumListBackward(int*, int):
    push    {r7}
    sub sp, sp, #20
    add r7, sp, #0
    str r0, [r7, #4]
    str r1, [r7]
    movs    r3, #0
    str r3, [r7, #8]
    ldr r3, [r7]
    subs    r3, r3, #1
    str r3, [r7, #12]
    b   .L8
.L9:
    ldr r3, [r7, #12]
    lsls    r3, r3, #2
    ldr r2, [r7, #4]
    add r3, r3, r2
    ldr r3, [r3]
    ldr r2, [r7, #8]
    add r3, r3, r2
    str r3, [r7, #8]
    ldr r3, [r7, #12]
    subs    r3, r3, #1
    str r3, [r7, #12]
.L8:
    ldr r3, [r7, #12]
    cmp r3, #0
    bge .L9
    ldr r3, [r7, #8]
    mov r0, r3
    adds    r7, r7, #20
    mov sp, r7
    ldr r7, [sp], #4
    bx  lr
```

Heck, you could probably make it more efficient if you wanted to. Its exactly the same number of instructions as summing the list forward though, so I would think that you would gain efficiency overall doing it this way - having two arrays in memory implies that you have to make both arrays, which takes clock cycles.

If we're talking about raw clock cycles, having one array and iterating over it in two ways is probably going to be faster.

Comment: Thanks Ken. That is a good point re clock cycles req to load the data into memory. I hadn't considered that. I don't have the luxury of using C it has to be hand coded in AVR assembly :)

Comment: @BenG I took a class doing assembly for the Freescale HCS12 series in college, can't say I envy you. I wish you luck in your quest for efficient assembly - and even more luck trying to beat out the gcc compiler in terms of code efficiency. It isn't easy! :)

Comment: Challenge accepted :)